# Nativescript/Angular BottomNavigation does not show

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am creating a playground app to test some features of the Nativescript `<BottomNavigation>` component, but I do not understand why the navigation bar (or the components within it) is not showing up. Would love for anyone to take a look:

https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=qjnAaa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem its the name of your tab component .. seems like the name of your component its in conflict with the new ns tabs component, check this 
https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=K3w4he&v=3